# Need to conduct Exploratory Factor Analysis when using already established questionnaire for Big 5

Tags: reference-request, statistics, big-five

I am working on a study where I plan to conduct Structural Equation Modeling with the Big 5 factors affecting another variable.

For Big 5 I am using a questionnaire that has earlier been used by others in the literature, and also using the same scoring system: basically, no change whatsoever.

Do I still need to conduct an Exploratory Factor Analysis (given that I have strong reasons to assert that there ought to be 5 factors, both theoretically and on the basis of past literature) or can I proceed directly to a Confirmatory Factor Analysis of my data on Big 5?

And to justify my work (of either conducting EFA or skipping it) what are some good sources to cite in my defence?